# How To Delete Every Row In A Table While Protecting First Row?

Tags: vba, ms-word, rowdeleting

The following code should delete every row but the first. However, it deletes every second row.

```vb
Dim index As Long
For index = 2 To ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count            
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(index).Delete
Exit For
Next
```

Comment: Probably best to loop from the bottom up.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `For index = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count to 2 Step -1`. Though I'm not sure what you're doing with `Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)`. Not a Word guy though.

Comment: Thank you sir!  Yea I didn't mean to put the selection in there lol.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to loop backwards using `Step -1`.

```
Dim index As Long
For index = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(index).Delete
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting just the *last* row is as simple as:

```
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  .Rows(.Rows.Count).Delete
End With
```